# How to enable/disable WebKit features when compiling as part of Qt5 library

Tags: c++, qt, webkit, qt5, qtwebkit

When you compile QtWebKit separately from Qt5, you have access to a bunch of compilation options, like --no-webkit2, --no-3d-rendering, --no-video and others. It seems that when you compile WebKit as part of the Qt5 library, you get stuck with predefined feature configuration which you cannot modify.

Is it possible to access the configuration features when you compile QtWebKit as part of the Qt5 source distribution? How can you pass the mentioned parameters to the WebKit build from the Qt5 build tools?

Comment: Not sure if they could go in as direct `configure` params. I remember using `-DENABLE_*` in `configure` to enable Webkit features.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that. It is so frustrating that each trial take hours to complete. :(

Comment: BTW, why don't you add an answer instead a comment?

Comment: not working. passing -D ENABLE_* won't work.

Comment: Ok. Then may be pro edits will help. But you will need to dig deep to identify each option. For e.g. I assume skipping this [line](https://github.com/qtproject/qt/blob/v4.8.6/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/WebKit.pro#L11) will ignore WebKit2 during qt build. About `ENABLE_*`, I remember enabling gelocation support with that option a couple of years back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile Qt first without QtWebKit (configure -skip qtwebkit), you can modify Tools/qmake/mkspecs/features/features.pri from the QtWebKit source to enable or disable features. Then generate Makefile from WebKit.pro and run nmake. Now QtWebKit should build with the features you've set.

Comment: To add to the answer, to disable `Webkit2` the option is in [Webkit.pro](https://github.com/qtproject/qtwebkit/blob/v5.4.2/WebKit.pro#L46). It is not in `features.pri`.